# Jquery hover btn - showing all

Tags: jquery

How do you specify each hover state using this code 
When you duplicate the html and hover over the button it displays all btns, not just one at a time

```
$(".show-pic-trigger").hover(function () {
    $(".show-btns-pic").show();
}, function () {
    $(".show-btns-pic").hide();
})
```

any help would be great

Comment: Can you show us your markup currently you are selecting all the .show-btns-pic

Comment: You need to show us the html as well so we can see the relationship between the trigger and the pic.

Comment: you need to share the relevant html so that we can have the relationship between `show-pic-trigger` and `show-btns-pic` elements

Comment: is this what you are looking for http://jsfiddle.net/CzM3X/3/

Answer (score -3):

You will have to make different classes of each element. After that you can also use 'toggleClass' function.

Comment: This isn't even remotely related to the question.

Comment: For 'hover' event to act over each button separately he needs to identify each button separately and for that he needs to add different classes(or ids) to each button.

Comment: Nop he doesn't all he needs is to show us the markup so we can see the relationship between show-pic-trigger and show-btns-pic so it would be something like $(this).closest(".show-btns-pic").show()

Comment: Ok. I might have misunderstood.